# Objective-C regex look-behind assertion must not contain * or + operators

Tags: objective-c, regex, foundation

According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009708-CH1-SW49),

> The length of possible strings matched by the look-behind pattern must
>   not be unbounded (no * or + operators.)

It appears that in Foundation's implementation of regex, `*` or `+` is not allowed in a look-behind assertion. That's not the case in regex libraries in many other languages. What's a common way to get around this limitation?

Comment: Perhaps you could give it some really high bounds - say, use `{0,1000}` in place of `*`.

Comment: If you post the expression with a lookbehind that gets rejected, perhaps someone could help you rewrite it to be suitable for Apple's regex engine.

Comment: That's a good idea! But I just wonder if there is any "idiom" or common pattern used by most Objc programmers to get around this limitation.

Comment: Thanks dasblinkenlight! In my specific case, I can use either a look-ahead or a look-behind. I wrote it as a look-behind initially and got rejected, then I figured out a way to rewrite it into a look-ahead, which allows `*` and `+`

Comment: Just FYI, Apple incorporates the [ICU regex engine](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp) as the basis for Foundation's regex capabilities. If you want, you might be able to find more information on this limitation using that.

Answer (score 1):

One way around this limitation is by stacking assertions, or by using group captures to capture specific sections within your match.

For example if you were looking at this string: `aaaa a baaba aa ababaa aaa aad aad adaaj aaaddajaaa`

And wanted to capture every letter preceded by one or more `a`, you could use this pattern and just capture the first group: `\ba+(\w)`.

That is not to say that this always is a viable solution, but in most cases it is possible to come to the desired result without using an unbounded look behind.

Answer (score 0):

`That's not the case in regex libraries in many other languages`

Actually, the reverse is true. It's the case in *almost all* other engines.

Some engines though allow alternations in lookbehind's, others lump that into variable length category.

Usually you don't need a variable length lookbehind.
You need it for a specific string acting as an *`anchor`* preceding a forward looking expression.

Possible workarounds:

Note - Using a lookahead in place of a variable length lookbehind is not the way to go.
This can be done for other purposes, but won't work how you think it will as a lookbehind replacement.

There is a construct `\K` available in Perl/PCRE compatible engines (and others).
From the  Perl docs:

```
There is a special form of this construct, called \K, which causes the regex engine
to "keep" everything it had matched prior to the \K and not include it in $&.
This effectively provides variable length look-behind. The use of \K inside of
another look-around assertion is allowed, but the behaviour is currently not
well defined.
```

Another way is to stack up separate lookbehinds.
Since the current match position does not change, you can stack assertions up as much as you want.

Example - `(?<!abcd)(?<=bcd)`